# How to mirror production SQL Server database with Local with ability to change local database for a period of time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, mirroring

I currently have a setup where I have a local website, a staging website, and a production website. I develop on my local using the staging database and then once the change is made, it is moved to staging, which configuration wise, is supposed to match production. If it works on staging, I pretty much know it'll work live, and I move it to production.

As of now, the staging database is out of date with the changes made in production by our users.

What I would like to hopefully accomplish would be to have some way that the staging database could be updated every night automatically. This would allow staging to be up to date, but allow us to make changes to staging that may be needed to test new changes, without it getting overridden immediately by a production update.

Microsoft SQL Server if that helps. Believe it is 2008.

To sum up, how would I be able to mirror Production database to staging database automatically every night?

Comment: Do you mean to update the structure of your database every night? or just update the data that it stores? This could create issues either way, and you may be better off running the job manually.

Comment: I guess just Data. Whenever we add a new table, it gets added to staging first then moved to production so therotically, the structure should always match.

Comment: Theoretically - you may come up with some issues with this. For instance, you updated your staging with a new structure (say a new column that doesn't allow NULLs and no default). you stop for the day and come back the next day, the update will fail because it couldn't copy the data into that structure. You're possibly better off creating a duplicate of the entire database, which can be set up by a job.

Comment: Could that duplicate be run every night or is that an on going real time thing? Does duplicating take an extreme amount of time if done remotely, aka the production database is stored in a different state than our local stating database? Would mirroring allow us to query the staging database? We could introduce a 3rd step, so local -> staging - > pre production -> production and have pre-production mirror production and occasionally mirror staging with preprduction so we would still have the playground.

Comment: If your DB (Production and Staging) are stored on the same server, it's pretty quick in most cases.

Comment: The two servers are not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25522/discussion-between-duniyadnd-and-solidsnake4444)

Answer (score 4):

If you can make sure to move schema changes from staging to production in 24 hour period. Then actually your task is easy to accomplish, just backup production db and restore on staging.

Log shipping and database mirroring can only leave you a read only db. Replication don't have the read only limitation, but it will fail if there are conflicts while you are updating the schema and data on staging db.

Your prod db is around 25G zipped, it is too large to transfer in daily basis I think. If its incremental changes are not that much, let say less than 500M zipped a day, I suggest you can use weekly full backup and daily differential backup strategy. This way you only need to set up 2 backup jobs on prod, and one restore job on staging, it is always just restore a full backup for this week and a new differential backup.

Pls note that you need to kill all connections on staging db before restoring it, alter database to singe user model to do it.

The full backup and log backup strategy should also work and need less data to transfer, but will be a bit complicate to set up the restore job.

Comment: This sounds like it would work but I'm a bit worried about it actually completing overnight. The backup would need to be done (I believe it is around 25 gbs Zipped), and then transferred over to our staging server (probably take a few hours) and then restored (however long that takes). Is there something we can do like do an initial and then increment only the changes so only the new data is added?

Comment: @JohnnyWei, could you elaborate why you say "Database mirror, log shipping or replication will not help" - is it because they all require "receiving" database to be in "restore" or single use mode (or similarly inoperable mode)? Could you comment on my suggestion in my answer.

Comment: @G.Stoynev, Yes, "receiving" database of database mirror and log shipping is read only. And replication db is operational, but will fail if there is any conflict. Seems like I don't have enough reputation to add comments in your answer. So I write it here. Your solution definately can work and it is highly efficient I think. But it needs some manual work once there are too many log files, or let say it is complicate to automate. And automation is very important in database administration work I think.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444, I just updated my answer, you can use a weekly full backup and daily differential backup strategy. It should be easy to automate.

Comment: @JohnyWei, To clarify - are you suggesting differentials instead of trans logs? Please factor in that development daily activities on the staging copy will throw off LSN chains. That's why I am suggesting staging nighly maintenance to always return to last full restore, before re-applying all trans log baks.

Comment: So your answer is going off the idea of local -> staging -> production and not G. Stoynev's way of local -> test -> new staging -> production? If so it sounds like you are saying we will update the staging database with a full backup on the weekend and then during the week at night, apply the differential backups (logs?) which will erase our test data we may have added and that'll bring us back up to how production was? If that is all correct, I think I like that idea. Is there an easy way to automate all of this or is there a predetermined tool that helps?

Comment: @SolidSnake4444, no, not all correct, for example weekly full backup  took on Sunday is A, and differential backup for Monday is B, so Production db for Monday will be A+B, differential backup for Tuesday is C, then A+C is the Tuesday prod db. So every night you need to apply A first then a differential backup B or C for that day. It should be very easy to automate those backup and restore jobs using sql agent.

Comment: @G.Stoynev, even with differential backup, a night full backup restore is needed, I suggest differential over tran backups just because it is easier to write automation script.

Comment: +JohnyWei, I understand that e always start with the full. I like your idea of diffs better than tran logs'.

Answer (score 1):

You have stated two contradictory goals.

1. You want the data refereshed nightly.
2. You want your schema changes preserved.

These goals are in conflict because the data and schema may no longer be compatible.  Simple exmple would be added or deleted columns, slightly more complex example would be a table constraint added to your staging db...if you are working on fixing some bad data and making sure it doesn't happen again, your production db would still have bad data in it.

I would suggest that you have a daily backup of your production data restored to staging (aka test) then run the scripts that you will be using to modify production qhen the time comes against test.  Unless you've got some really heaviy duty data and changes, this should be fairly quick.  Possibly quickly enough that you won't want to automate it (easier to see what happen when and if it fails).

You can automate both of these steps if you like, using sql agent.

Comment: The scehema changes in staging will always be in sync as we always add to staging and then to production. We would just have to make sure to do that within the 24 hour period to make sure the change isn't overwritten by the mirror. What would be the job that the SQL agent would run? I heard that were a couple of different mirror types.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444: I wouldn't use mirroring, mainly because I haven't, and I'm not sure f the benefits in this scenario.  I would have a job that does a full backup and a job that does a restore.  Then any scripts that you have run against your staging.

Answer (score 1):

Good questions.  I do something very similar to this in my development environment.

What I do is have multiple staging databases.  Once is the active one, and one is available to restore backups to from the production system.  As things progress I end up switching from one staging database to the other with the staging servers.

To move the schema I use 2 tools both from RedGate. First SQL Source control allows me to check in all of the databse schema so that it can be kept in source control.  Second is SQL Compare which allows me to compare the schema between 2 databses and then migrate one to the other.

The process involves bringing a backup of production to development, then migrating the schema changes with SQL Compare from the old staging DB to the new staging DB. Then all the development and staging servers are switched to point to the new staging DB.

Flip flop back and forth between the two staging servers over time, you always have one active development server, and one that can be restored to.

When you want to move your schema changes to production just use SQL Compare from RedGate to create a change script.

I have been using this process for almost 4 years (SQL Source Control for 2), and it works great for multiple developers, and for pushing changes to production.

Check out SQL Compare and SQL Source Control from RedGate.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer - I am intrinsically familiar with @SolidSnake4444's setup and goals)

@jmoreno is correctly observing a contradiction.

Large database size is another factor that works against a solution that relies on a scheduled complete restore.

I feel the best solution is a hybrid of @JohnyWeil's and @SteveStedman's suggestions, as follows:
1. Create a second "real" staging local database - this one will be a mirror of production data and schema.
2. Start calling your current "staging" a "test" or "dev".
3. Setup log shipping from production to new staging, but delay applying the logs.

Note, 3. is needed, because of an implied requirement that this "staging" database has to be operational, to allow "staging" or "pre-deployment testing" local activities. The "operational" requirement rules out any type of "live" synchronization - mirroring or replication, because daily "local" activities will most certainly generate lots of data, conflicting with what's being generated in production; schema changes are also possible. (Please someone correct me, if I am wrong).

Also, on a weekly or bi-weekly basis (basically when the number of trans. log backup restores needed becomes impractically high), pull down a full backup from production and remove old accumulated transactional log backups to reset the cycle.

All of this can be completely automated.